XCode 16.0 Failed to build ios it exited with error code 65
I have recently upgraded my macOS version to macOS Sequoia 15.0, and as per consequence I have upgraded my Xcode version to 16.0.
When I build my react native app on my terminal it shows error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app
When I try to build it in Xcode, it fails with a crash

Xcode throws a Logic Error - Division by Zero

How can I fix this? I cannot run my react native app at all



What is your programming question for the Stack Overflow community?

what can I do to run my react native project, it gives me the error I have provided above?

You are saying that the words "Xcode throws a Logic Error - Division by Zero" actually appear somewhere? Where do they appear?

@Piepants your comment is even more ridiculous than the question itself.... Your comment has part of truth but did in any way not help anyone also... Question to the question author - how did you try to run the application, from CLI or trough the Xcode, I can't figure out? What version of react you are using etc... It need so much more details to give proper help

@TarvoMäesepp Both: when I run from the cli it gives me fail to build error code 65, in xcode division by 0. The react native version I am using:     "react-native": "0.72.4",

In my Imac (where I have not done the upgrade it works fine), in the macbook it gives me this error after upgrading

In Xcode try Command + Shift + K(this cleans your project) and after that Command + Shift + R(that builds it without  using cache I think) try if that makes any difference.

it makes no difference unfortunately

Okay, I think I see what's going on. If this is React's code, they need to change it.
The idea here, apparently, is to deliberately divide by zero and thus cause a runtime error. But unfortunately for that plan, the Swift compiler catches the division by zero, and stops the code from even compiling. The code you've shown therefore contains a "trick" that tries to hide the division by zero from the compiler; apparently, that used to be sufficient, but the compiler is now too smart, and catches it anyway.
The React people can revise the code as follows to work around the problem:
@objc public func invokeNC(_ x: Int = 1) {
    var zero = 1
    zero = zero - x
    _ = 1/zero
}

That hides the division from the compiler, but crashes when called at runtime.
